# Проблема с BackSpace

Tags: vb.net

Есть такой код

```
Sub time_pause_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles KeyBind.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode >= 49 And e.KeyCode <= 57 Then
            get_key_rule = get_key_rule & Chr(e.KeyCode)
        End If
    End Sub
```

При нажатии на BackSpace - ничего не происходит. Что делать?

Comment: Так Вы его и не обрабатываете.

Comment: If e.KeyCode >= 49 And e.KeyCode <= 57 Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then

Comment: или проверить что e.KeyCode = 8